# ReloadSections on a UITableView ignores no animation on the first time

Tags: ios, uitableview

This code is part of a callback on a click on an button in a `UITableViewCell`

While the animation is none - on the first time the button is clicked, I still see some sort of scroll that stops the cell on the top of the screen (usually it gets me to the same position but with a weird scroll) the next times it does what it needs to do

Refreshes the cell according to the new data (a boolean causing the button color to change)

How come?

```
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(4, 1);
    NSIndexSet *section = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];
    [self.tableView reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)section withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

**Edit:**
It looks like the tableview is getting scrolled all the way from the top up until the section...

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any calls to scrollToRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: There is one call unrelated in a different function, doesn't get executed (verified it with a breakpoint)

Comment: I'm seeing calls to `heightForRowAtIndexPath` for different sections. Can it be related? why is it happening?